Saved app data via Google Drive API not displayed account's Storage Manager
I'm accessing Google Drive via DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA and saving data to the "appDataFolder".
I understand this data is hidden and not intended to be displayed normally in Google Drive. It's visible only from certain locations.

From the Google Account's Storage Manager https://one.google.com/u/1/storage/management, my app nor the data is not listed.  I can see WhatsApp, but not my app.
From the Google Drive App under Menu/Backups, I also do not see my app, only WhatsApp.

In Google Account's Third-party apps & services, I confirmed my app is listed (along with WhatsApp).
I can also programmatically display the list of all files I saved to Google Drive.
I also have a decrease in available storage from space that's been consumed from my data.
I'm sure my data is present, but it's not listed.
Here's my sample code to generate mock test data
// A loremp ipsum string of 1024 bytes
private const val MOCK_TEXT = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sollicitudin bibendum metus, quis placerat risus placerat sit amet. In eu eros consectetur, suscipit nulla ut, porta dui. Nulla accumsan, libero ac vestibulum aliquam, tortor elit aliquet neque, non suscipit erat augue at dui. Etiam iaculis vitae ex vitae elementum. Quisque laoreet convallis arcu ut dictum. Ut non blandit ipsum, at rhoncus lorem. Donec non finibus diam, ac consequat augue.
Sed convallis in magna vel pharetra. Vestibulum eu enim in ex hendrerit vestibulum eu sed tortor. Donec egestas, neque nec pulvinar euismod, nulla odio pulvinar felis, a vulputate lectus turpis sit amet justo. Proin ultrices porttitor aliquam. Mauris rhoncus luctus gravida. Praesent pharetra tempor vulputate. In pretium feugiat leo eget porttitor.
Morbi vel tristique leo. Pellentesque pretium eros magna, ac interdum ipsum aliquam in. Proin sapien quam, mollis vitae scelerisque nec, euismod nec enim. Maecenas magna quam, ornare sed est a, aliquam pellentesque eu.
"""

private fun generateData(): String {
    val items = mutableListOf<String>()
    repeat(1024) {
        items.add(MOCK_TEXT)
    }
    return items.joinToString()
}

private fun generateFile(fileName: String): GFile {
    return GFile().apply {
        this.name = fileName
        this.parents = listOf("appDataFolder")
    }
}


private fun saveMockData(context: Context, accessToken: String) {
    val credentials = GoogleCredentials.create(AccessToken(accessToken, Date.from(timeNow().plusMinutes(5).toInstant())))
    val requestInitializer = HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials)

    val drive = Drive
        .Builder(
            NetHttpTransport(),
            GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
            requestInitializer
        )
        .setApplicationName("MyApp")
        .build()

    val request = drive.about().get()
    request.fields = "user"
    val user = request.execute().user.emailAddress

    repeat(10) { count ->
        val gfile = generateFile("Mock File $count")
        val content = ByteArrayContent("text/plain", generateData().toByteArray())
        drive.Files().create(gfile, content).setFields("id").execute()
        val result = drive.files().list().setSpaces("appDataFolder").setFields("*").execute()
        val totalSize = result.files.sumOf { it.quotaBytesUsed }.div(1024).div(1024)
        Timber.v("Total Size: $totalSize")
    }

    val result = drive.files().list().setSpaces("appDataFolder").setFields("*").execute()
    result.files.forEach { file ->
        Timber.d("${file.name} [${file.quotaBytesUsed}]")

        // To Delete Files
        // drive.Files().delete(file.id).execute()
    }
}

fun Context.uriForFile(file: File): Uri {
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.FILE_PROVIDER, file)
}


